# The argument type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. How can ı use the await?

Tags: flutter, dart

how can i solve this? I need to get the email value.
[image]

Comment: It is not a good practice to upload images of your code. Write your code instead.

Comment: You can't just write random code and hope it works. The "then" method returns a Future you need to handle. I recommend reading about async programming in Dart: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: Please provide an block of codes, image hater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that! You can't affect a future to a property.

You need to first get the value and then affect it to property, like this:

```
void _newRegisterMethod() async {
    String myValue = await _loginEmail();
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FormWidget(loginEmail: myValue)));
}
```

Assuming that `_loginEmail` is a method, not a var, because in your code you have `_loginEmail.then`, guess it miss parenthesis.

Comment: @SonerB You're welcome, don't forget to checkmark answer.